# create list of  content titles at end of each articles

Tags: views, blocks

I want create block, view first articles as full node and others just view titles at the end of first articles.

for instace:  when create content type like 'opinion' and show 10 articles on every page, how view first articles (newest) as full node and 9 articles just view titles.

I used drupal 6

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a views display in which you'll show complete node and add an attachment to display which'll show the titles of all the other nodes.

Comment: Dear Can you tell me how put a default title for attachment because of I put a title in "title" section but didn't appeared on page (for instance "other articles" or "related"?

Comment: Add header field in the attachment. Kindly accept the answer.